# how can i fix this while in a void?

Tags: processing

```java
void setup() {
  size(800,600);
  smooth();
}
void draw() {
 int circlex = 0;
 int circley = 0;
 while(true){
   ellipse(circlex,circley,50,50);
   circlex = circlex + 2;
   circley = circley + 1;
 }
}
```

I'm very new to Java and I want to know why this only shows a background and nothing happens.

Comment: Is this Processing?

Comment: *why this only shows a background* I don't see a background in the code...  `while(true){` are you using Swing? That's likely going to block the EDT and freeze your GUI forever... But, better, post a valid [mcve] and what is the code intended to do?

Comment: probably need to set the fill and line color of the ellipse being drawn. its current color are still the same as the background color, just a guess. try this https://processing.org/reference/fill_.html

Comment: you don't need a `while(true)` anyway because `draw()` loops forever, until stopped. Also, you'll want to define the `circlex` and `circley` before the void draw otherwise you'll reset it to `0` each time the method is called.

Comment: this should solve your issue `void setup() {
  size(800,600);
  smooth();
}

 int circlex = 0;
 int circley = 0;
void draw() {
   background(255,56,98);
   ellipse(circlex,circley,50,50);
   circlex = circlex + 2;
   circley = circley + 1;
}`, basically a moving ellipse.

Comment: Coming back to your question _I want to know why this only shows a background and nothing happens_. this is because of the `while(true)` is looping infinitely, meaning you're preventing the `draw()` method to be invoked again in order to display the current location of the ellipse.

Comment: Please note that this is a [tag:processing] question, and [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java). Specifically, this code **is** a complete valid MCVE in Processing. I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite while loop is blocking rendering, so your sketch is never finishing rendering a frame. The `draw()` function already gets called multiple times per second: use that as your infinite loop.

Also move your local variables to the top of your code so they're visible through out the Processing sketch. This way you won't reset the values back to 0 all the time, cancelling out the position incrementation:

```
int circlex = 0;
int circley = 0;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  smooth();
}
void draw() {


  ellipse(circlex, circley, 50, 50);
  circlex = circlex + 2;
  circley = circley + 1;
}
```

Comment: It gave me an error when I did that before, but it works now. Weird.